# How error syntax in appbar and return Scaffold

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: firebase,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Error"),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Text("${snapshot.error}"),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    _header(context),
                    _inputField(context),
                    _forgotPassword(context),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

In case Have error in the syntax how I can fix it after I delete scaffold It can't run and I put it I can't run it same
appbar:Appbar(line25(line8 in stackoverflow))it error I don't know how fix it some people can help me for fix
it and line174-181(line44-52 in stackoverflow) have error every time I can't work it
Thank for your guidance

Comment: The question is unclear. Please follow [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold is the first item that builds the UI you cant change it while you're on the same page, instead of all your code just try the code below it will solve your problem.

```
Material(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: firebase,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar:
            snapshot.hasError ? AppBar(title: const Text("Error")) : null,
        body: snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                ? Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          _header(context),
                          _inputField(context),
                          _forgotPassword(context),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}")),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```